# Simple Prime Numbers Program.... What is wrong with my code/script?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, numbers

I am wondering I can get some help at debugging or spotting the error in my program. The objective is to obtain user input and then display primes from input to zero, greatest prime to lowest.

Problem is the output includes the user input which may or may not be a prime number in itself, and repeats primes several times :(
Also, I am wondering why 2 isn't included?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int prime, division, input;
    cout << "Please enter a number you wish to count down prime numbers from." << endl;
    cin >> input;

    for (prime = input ; prime >=2 ; prime-- )
    {
        for (division = 2 ; division < prime ; division++ )
        {
            if (prime % division == 0)
            {
            break;
            }
            else
            {
            cout << prime << " ";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

Please enter a number you wish to count down prime numbers from.
15

15 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 9 7 7 7 7 7 5 5 5 3

Thanks for those who help!

Comment: You should be creating a separate function to find if a number is prime or not.

Comment: For a number **n**, there would be no multiples for it from numbers greater than **n/2** other than itself. Use this to improve the efficiency. For **15** there would be no multiples for it from **8** to **14**.

Comment: Script? C++ is not a scripting language, the name of what you typed is Code or Program, not script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int prime, division, input;
    cout << "Please enter a number you wish to count down prime numbers from." << endl;
    cin >> input;




    for (prime = input ; prime >=2 ; prime--)
    {
        boolean isDivisible = false;
        for (division = 2 ; division < prime ; division ++)
        {
            if (prime % division == 0)
            {
                isDivisible = true;
            }
        }
        if (isDivisible == false)
        {
            cout << prime << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan!
It works very well with boolean variables, but I am wondering if you know a method which will work Without them?

Comment: I am taking an online course, and can only use knowledge from sections covered :(
Boolean variables would be great here too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a program which tells whether the input number is prime or not.Any number is completely divisible by a number which is always less than it.
In case of prime numbers they are completely divisible by 1 and itself;
So i have used a counter variable which counts how many times a number is completely divisible by a number or numbers less than it.
The count will be always 2 for prime numbers and count will be more than two for others.
Count will be 1 for one...
So the program is as follows....

```
    #include<iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    class prime
    {
       int a;
       public:
         void check();

    };
       void prime::check()
                         {
                          cout<<"Insert a number";
                          cin>>a;
                          int count=0;
                          for(int i=a;i>=1;i--)
                             {
                                if(a%i==0)
                                      {
                                        count++;
                                       }
                               }
                                 if(count==1)
                                           {
                                cout<<"\nOne is neither prime nor composite";
                                            }
                                  if(count>2)
                                           {
                                cout<<"\nthe number is not prime its composite" ;
                                           }
                                 if(count==2)
                                          {    
                                cout<<"\nthe numner is prime";
                                           }
             }

     void main()
     {
      clrscr();
     prime k;
     k.check();
     getch();
     }
```

To print all the prime numbers less than the number given as input; code is as follows:

```
      #include<iostream.h>
      #include<stdio.h>
      #include<conio.h>
        class prime
        {
               int a;
               int i;
        public:
          void display();
        };

          void prime::display()
                   {
                     cout<<"Enter any number to find primes less than it";
                     cin>>a;
                        int count=0;
                     for(int j=a;j>=1;j--)
                      {
                        for(int i=1;i<=j;i++)
                             {
                                if(j%i==0)
                                         {
                                           count++;
                                          }
                               }
                        if(count==2)
                                   {
                                     cout<<"\n"<<j;
                                    }
                         count=0;
                        }
                  }
     void main()
     {
        clrscr();
        prime k;
        k.display();
        getch();
      }
```

Comment: Have you considered indenting your code? If you indent it like the example code in the question, it'll be far easier for a reader to understand its behaviour.

Comment: @DanHulmethe;buddy i havent learnt indentation properly, i love to apply logic;but i thank u for u'r instruction; will try my best.Thanx for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem:

for 9, when `division == 2`, `9 % 2 ==1`, so 9 is printed.Rather than You should have a flag value to denote if a number is prime or not, and print the number after you are sure it is prime.

For 2, EDIT: when `prime == 2`, and because `division < prime` is the condition that the inner loop get executed, the inner loop exits without running. All credits go to Marlon!

Comment: Actually for his second problem, when `prime` is 2 the second loop's condition will evaluate to false (`2 < 2`) and exit the loop immediately.

Comment: On a thing not your problem: division only has to go up to (and including) the sqrt(prime)

Comment: @Marlon Ah, crap, talked too fast. Thanks!

Comment: Thank yoy Marlon and Ziyao Wei for you contributuion.
@Marlon, if I wanted to fix the expression can I simply change it to division <= prime ?
ZiyaoWei, I am rather new to C++, how can I "flag the value"?

Comment: @albertoroberto: first: Don't change it to that, or prime % prime will always be 0 and then you'll never get a prime! just fix the first part then the second part will be also fixed. And you could just use a boolean value to check if the current "prime" is prime or not; after the inner loop finished, if you still are sure that it is a prime, print it; anytime you find it to be a composite, change the boolean to false.

Answer (score 0):

Check your inner for loop. Each run through the loop, your initializer gets reset to 2. Then you do Mod 2 on the suspected prime. If you get 0, all you really know is that the number is even. That might lead you to quickly say that the number isn't prime, but 2 mod 2 is 0, and 2 is prime. After the loop, "division" becomes 3. 15 mod 3 is 0. At that point, you break out of the loop, but 15 is NOT prime. Check your algorithm for determining primes. You could have it check against known primes, but that's not dynamic enough. There are other methods, one of which revolves around determining the suspected prime number's square root. Finally, you could do some good old (long) paper-pencil debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is not correct. Its not printing primes, just odd numbers. It checks whether a number is divisible by 2 during first iteration and an even number will always be divisble. So the inner loop always breaks out if the number is even but it prints the number if odd and continues doing so till the loop breaks or terminates.

Lets try to get this with an example, the outer loop is at 9. The inner loop will check if its divisble by 2, since its not it'll print out the number and continue again. Next iteration will check whether its divisible by 3, since it is it'll break out.

And try using a function to check whether a number is prime that makes it more modular. Here's a little optimized version...

```
bool prime(int num)
{
    int root = sqrt(num);
    if(num == 2)
        return true;
    if(num%2 == 0)
        return false;
    for(int i=3;i<=root+1;i=i+2)
        if(num % i == 0)
           return false;
    return true;
}
```